# Book recommendation for measure theory (general measure)

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I know there questions book recommendation for measure theory. But, I need to know about good book for learn **general measure** part in measure theory. do you know any? Please comment thanks.

Comment: Folland real analysis

Comment: Theory of Measure and Integration, J Yeh.

Comment: Real Analysis by Elias M. Stein, one of the best.

Comment: Fremlin https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm or Royden, Real Analysis, 3rd (not 4th).

Answer (score 4):

I do not agree with Folland for measure theory. It contains only the bare minimum one should know.

I would recommend *Measure theory Vol 1 & 2* by Bogachev. Although massive, it is very pedagogical. It contains A LOT of fairly new results that you most likely do not find in most textbooks.

Comment: I realise that Bogachev books used to assume finite measure space? Of course, he is a well-known probability researcher.